# tesseract not reading numbers when barcode is present in image file

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have been trying to read numbers from an image file which contains barcode followed by numbers. If I crop numbers alone and run below code it returns me the numbers as text (exact result).

`tesseract.doOCR(new File("C:\\XXXXX\\teess.jpg"));`

But I could not input numbers alone. My image file input contains barcode followed by numbers.(This itself a subimage() of another main image file again parsing to the point of exact numbers would be difficult may be missing out few characters).   But if I give image with barcode (i.e) my actual input always I am getting below value. Some random characters instead of numbers. Has anyone got any idea would be helpful.

*Text is ::Sample # 38
“'!'JJ'J'L'1'L!“L"‘|*

My input image file is a barcode which followed by actual value. [image]

And warnings found in the log :

> Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch Warning: Invalid
> resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.

Comment: @MartinZeitler My previous question got closed because lack of clarity. I am trying two approaches to get content from image file. A) Using OCR, b) Using Zxing.  So I have created two different questions in order to have better clarity. When I gave both questions together few in this forum down voting and make that question invalid. I have no choice of writing back into 2 separate Q. Thanks.

Comment: same issue here - Tesseract works well until barcode is involved. Have you found a solution @aarav?